# Changing a CALayer contents before animation finished

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, calayer

I work on a UI component that implements flip-card clock animation. All works fine, but when I change a top CALayer contents to new image, the old image stays visible before changeding. It creates confusion effect. For better explanation I place the gif animation bellow:

[image]

This is code with changing a CALayer contents:

```
firstTopLayer.contents = secondTopLayer.contents
let bottomAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
bottomAnim.duration = animDuration/2
bottomAnim.repeatCount = 1
bottomAnim.fromValue = NSValue.init(caTransform3D:
CATransform3DMakeRotation((CGFloat)(M_PI_2), 1, 0, 0))
bottomAnim.toValue = NSValue.init(caTransform3D:
CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 1, 0, 0))
bottomAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
bottomAnim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
firstBottomLayer.add(bottomAnim, forKey: "bottom")
firstBottomLayer.contents = self.bufferContents
```

For more information I place a link to the [repository](https://github.com/ftp27/FTPFlipNumber/blob/master/FTPFlipNumber/Classes/FTPFlipNumber.swift#L151-L168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Top animation must have this configuration

```
topAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
topAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

and after each start this animation.

```
firstTopLayer.removeAnimation(forKey: kTopAnimaton)
```

With this configuration the top layer stays in it last frame animation position